# Kerberos across multiple forests

Tags: kerberos

I have two DC's in separate forests(abc.com and xyz.com) & I have a trust between them. And I have a kerberos realm trust between abc.com KDC and  Zscaler(a http proxy service running in cloud). This trust is transitive.

Now, I have a client(user) who is part of xyz.com.
User logs in as user@xyz.com to the machine.
He would open his browser and try to browse through.
He would send a HTTP GET to the Zscaler proxy.(lets say abc.com).
Zscaler would redirect the user to get a service ticket, before accessing abc.com.
This user has to ask for TGT from xyz.com for abc.com.
Then the client should ask for a TGT to abc.com for Zscaler KDC.
Then client will request a service ticket from Zscaler KDC.

The problem I am facing is this.
How do I make my client request a TGT for abc.com and then ask for a TGT to abc.com for Zscaler KDC.

In this scenario, only abc.com KDC has a realm trust with Zscaler KDC.

Comment: Are you developing the 'client' yourself, or is it already written (for example web browser)? What application is used in the 2nd paragraph? What sends HTTP GET to the Zscaler?

Comment: To check trust-relationship configuration please follow: https://support.zscaler.com/hc/en-us/articles/204843759

Comment: Hi Greenmarker, I just edited the query to be more clear.. The user would  open the browser and then access any website. That is when Zscaler will redirect him to get a service ticket.

Comment: Hi Greenmarker, the link you shared does not cover when there are multiple domains in the forest. It covers the scenario of a single domain and forming realm trust with Zscaler.